# Is CTE's stored (like a table) or do you create it each time you need it? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

Never worked with MS SQL Server before and the CTE's is new to me. But it's exactly what I need in the project I just started.

Have a table that looks like

```
TABLE group (
 'id' int,
 'parentId' int,
 'groupName' varchar(255)
)
```

So I have a dynamic page and depending on a get parameter, "Group" I want all that's below this group returned. I'm pretty sure I can manage to write the CTE for it as well as use it.

But do I create it each time I wish to use it? (basically connect to DB, run the setup for the CTE, then use a query running on this). 
Or are they stored in the database once they're created and ready to be used whenever?

If they are stored, is there any command similar to sp_tables, etc to show it /them?
Cause if they're saved there probably already exist a query that does this.

Comment: A CTE is not a view. If you don't understand this then they're not "exactly what (you) need"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A CTE is just a different way of formin a SQL expression.

Where one comment states that it "is not a view", it is fairly similar to an inline-view.  The difference being that you can reference it several times in the same query, or have recursive declarations...

```
WITH cte AS (...) SELECT * FROM cte

is similar to

SELECT * FROM (...)
```

They are not, however, persisted.  You can't even do the following...

```
WITH
  cte AS
(
  ...
)

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM cte

SELECT * FROM cte
```

The SELECT INTO will work, but by the time of the second select, the CTE is out of scope...

Answer (score 3):

CTE are evaluated/created/consumed at run time. They're available only to the next single SQL statement that follows after the `WITH ... SELECT`.

You *could* insert their resultset into a table variable or temp table to have their results available for a longer duration.

You may be thinking of a View.

Comment: Well it's the recursive bit I need, can you do that in a view?
And recursive search based on a parameter. 

But that they are evaluated/... at run time answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: What you may find useful is to encapsulate this in a Table Valued Function, and use a CTE within it's definition.  Also note; to make a Table Valued Function as performant as possible, define it Inline rather than Multi-Statement.  You can then (efficiently) use CROSS APPLY to effectively join another table to the function, similar to how you would do so with a view.  (Happy googling if you're unfamiliar with any of that terminology.)

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

> A common table expression (CTE) can be
>   thought of as a **temporary result set
>   that is defined within the execution
>   scope of a single SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW
>   statement**. A CTE is similar to a
>   derived table in that it is not stored
>   as an object and **lasts only for the
>   duration of the query**. Unlike a
>   derived table, a CTE can be
>   self-referencing and can be referenced
>   multiple times in the same query.

Comment: This wording on Docs is still _very_ ambiguous and is the reason that we often find ourselves asking the same question as OP. While we can _think_ of them as temporary result sets, they are not _strictly_ evaluated in that way. It is more appropriate to think of them as _inline views_.